# Changing the span of a link in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to toggle the span of a link in html once it is clicked

```html
<a onClick="change_min()"><span id="glyph" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function change_min() {
    var btn = document.getElementById("glyph");
    if (btn.attr('class') == 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus') {
      btn.removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-plus').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-minus');
    } else {
      btn.removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-minus').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-plus');
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: what type of error did you getting in that code.

you can try using jquery

Comment: the button did not change to "-" when i clicked on the "+" link
can you please help

Comment: see i have added working code below in answer

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be mixing jQuery and plain javascript functions. When you use getElementById, this is not a jQuery object, and therefore `.attr()`, `.removeClass()`, `.addClass()` do not exist.

Instead select your btn like this:

```
btn = $("#glyph");
```

I would also use `.hasClass()` instead of `.attr()`.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#change-icon").on("click", function(e) {
    console.log('click');
    e.preventDefault();
    var btn = $("#glyph");
    if(btn.hasClass('glyphicon-plus')) {
      btn.removeClass('glyphicon-plus').addClass('glyphicon-minus');
    }
    else {
      btn.removeClass('glyphicon-minus').addClass('glyphicon-plus');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<a id="change-icon"><span id="glyph" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @sid See the snippet I've added.

Answer (score 0):

this will help you much.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("#linkclick").click(function(e) {
    if ($("#glyph").hasClass("glyphicon-plus")) {
      $("#glyph").removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
    } else {
      $("#glyph").addClass("glyphicon-plus").removeClass("glyphicon-minus");
    }


    e.preventDefault();
    //turn false;

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a href="#" id="linkclick"><span id="glyph" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
```